# Passing in argument to method: Should argument be retained?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

If I have a custom method like this:

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)myArgument 
{
      //do something with myArgument
}
```

is myArgument guaranteed to stick around for the execution of that method if i don't take ownership of it?

**EDIT**
Let me elaborate further. Say i call this somewhere:

```
[self myMethod:_myIvar];
```

and then somewhere else, while myMethod is executing, someone calls this:

```
[_myIvar release];
```

does that effect the argument within myMethod?

**END EDIT**

Looking through documentation/sample code, i rarely see a [myArgument retain] or [myArgument copy] at the top of a custom method. So is it unnecessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myArgument` is a valid object at the start of `myMethod`, and you do nothing to cause it to be deallocated or otherwise collected during the method, then yes, `myArgument` will still be a valid object at the end of the method.

**EDIT** in response to question's edit: let's talk about object ownership in this case. When you're passed `myArgument` as an argument to your function, you - in the context of `myMethod` - don't declare an interest in the object by `retain`ing or `copy`ing it. In such a situation, the only owners of the object exist outside `myMethod`.

If the last owner of `myArgument` decides that it's done with `myArgument` and `release`s it, then it's entirely possible that `myArgument` goes away - there are no strong references to the object any more that would keep it around. It *may* be valid, depending on threading concerns, autorelease pools involved, and a whole host of other issues, but that's a dangerous game to play. If there's even a possibility that such a situation might happen, you should explicitly declare an interest in `myArgument` within `myMethod`, as recommended by the [Memory Management Policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

Comment: Lets say i pass in an ivar, and lets say the ivar gets released somewhere else during the execution of the myMethod: function. The argument is still guarenteed to stick around?

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser you just stated the exact *opposite* condition Tim specified would be required for the argument to be retained. I'm going on a gut here and suggesting: no.

Answer (score 0):

If it is even possible that another thread can cause the object referenced by myArgument to be deallocated then myArgument can become a pointer to junk memory at any time and you will crash.

This is nothing to do with not retaining it in **-myMethod**. You are just as likely to crash during the retain method call. Rather you have a broken, unworkable threading model / architecture in your app that you must fix.

This is why threading is hard.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not guaranteed. You should call `retain` on anything you wish to keep hold of and `release` when finished. Otherwise another thread and dealloc it in the meantime.

I've had that bite me when writing an A* algorithm for a game.